# Python to Arduino UDP communication

Tags: python, c++, arduino, udp

I'm having troubles sending integers from python to Arduino Leonardo, I have the following scenario:

I have 4 integers, x-y coordinates usually 3 numbers and I want to send them over UDP to the arduino, and at the arduino the input serial data is stored in a buffer which at the end the following function is used to retrieve the data.

```
  if (Serial1.available() > 0) {

    // We rotate the Buffer
    for (i = (PACKET_SIZE - 1); i > 0; i--)
    {
      SBuffer[i] = SBuffer[i - 1];
    }
      SBuffer[0] = Serial1.read();

......
        dump = extractParamInt(10);
        x= extractParamInt(8);
        y= extractParamInt(6);
        x1= extractParamInt(4);
        y1= extractParamInt(2);

}

uint16_t extractParamInt(uint8_t pos) {
  union {
    unsigned char Buff[2];
    uint16_t d;
  }
  u;

  u.Buff[0] = (unsigned char)SBuffer[pos];
  u.Buff[1] = (unsigned char)SBuffer[pos + 1];
  return (u.d);
}
```

Im having difficulties sending raw bytes from python to the buffer, the arduino treats each b'xxx' as a byte and stores it in a buffer index.

So how do I send my 4 values which are often more than 255 to arduino, and make the arduino function combine the sent values into uint16_t correctly?

One thing I know is that the buffer should contain an upper byte and a lower byte so they're combined into uint16_t, but i cannot send 8 bits from python so the arduino proccesses it using serial.read as a one byte.

I have tried struct.pack, string.encode('ascii'), i can't get a solid method to send my values correctly.

Python Code:

```
# values:
dump = 0 
x = 433
y = 223
x1 = 233
y1 = 322
payload = 10

# desire
MESSAGE = 'mm1{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(dump,int(x),int(y),int(x1),int(y1),payload)
# sock.sendto(MESSAGE.encode('ascii'), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

# testing
sock.sendto(b'\x5f\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x07\x01\xcc\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x8b', (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Comment: Sounds like the problem is on your python end, show your python code

Comment: I have edited the original post.